# Internal linking in tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a749522038ed7786c3e1701435dcb891e) to create simple pdf document.

I am creating a page and adding link using below code

```
$pdf->addTOCPage();
$link = $pdf->AddLink();
$pdf->SetLink($link, 0, -1);
```

Now link is set successfull.But to navigate to that page what should I add ?
I tried below code , but it does nothing,

`<a href="#Whattoaddhere" style="color:blue;">Return to TOC</a>`

Comment: On the doc page you linked the third parameter of SetLink is a number, why do you pass a string?

Comment: @wOxxOm : editted the question

Comment: @wOxxOm : editted again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 // Create a fixed link to the first page using the * character
 $index_link = $pdf->AddLink();
 $pdf->SetLink($index_link, 0, '*1');
 $pdf->Cell(0, 10, 'Link to INDEX', 0, 1, 'R', false, $index_link);
```

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_045.phps

update -
refer to this function addHtmlLink() in tcpdf library.
You can add a internal link through this

```
 $pdf->addHtmlLink('#'.$index_link, 'hello');
```

where 'hello' begin the name of anchor and and first param being identifier to the link.

In your case

```
 $pdf->addHtmlLink('#'.$link, 'Whatever you like to name it');

 $html = '<a href="#'.$link.'" style="color:blue;">link name</a>';
 $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Comment: How can I use it inside writehtml() like <a href='.$index_link.'

Comment: *1 represents the page no.

Comment: I mean how to navigate to $index_link via <a href

Comment: Yea I use that but How can I use inside html..i.e inside writehtml function

Comment: Yupe I use that But it is going to page numbers only..not to table of contents.

Comment: Thanks for help though :) I am using addhtmllink.

Comment: AddLink() link return an identifier. This identifier is passed to any Cell(), Write(), Image() or Link(). Now this identifier will point this Cell(), write or link(). The identifier will work as link when passed to addHtmlLink().

Comment: yea it works in cell , write or link...but its not working for addHtmlLink ,..It just navigates to pagenumber...not the correct place where setlink is placed